# How to get first possible match using preg match in php

Tags: php, preg-match

I have one string like this

```
var str = 'abcd [[test search string]] some text here ]]';
```

I have tried like this

```
* preg_match("/\[\[test.*\]\]/i",$str,$match);
```

If I execute this, I am getting the output like the below

```
[[test search string]] some text here ]]
```

I want the first match only like

```
[[test search string]]
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$str = "var str = 'abcd [[test search string]] some text here ]]';";

preg_match("/(\[\[test[^]]*\]\])/im", $str, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 11):

Short answer: Yes you can.
You need to use lazy quantifiers.  So instead of

```
preg_match("/[[test.*]]/i",$str,$match);
```

use

```
preg_match("/\[\[test.*?\]\]/i",$str,$match);
```

to make the function stop at the first match.
Note: if you want to match a literal `[` or `]`charactor you need to escape them like: `\[` or `\]`.

After a little reaserch on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) I discovered a pattern modifier `U` (PCRE_UNGREEDY) that will set the default for the pattern to lazy as apposed to greedy.
So this means that

```
preg_match("/\[\[test.*\]\]/iU",$str,$match);
```

will also suit for this purpose.  The `U` modifier will make all `*`, `+`, `?` in the regex match as few characters as possible. Also, quantifiers that used to be ungreedy (`*?`, `+?`, and `??`) will now become greedy (match as many characters as possible).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However, the U modifier reverses the greediness, and thus makes `*?` greedy instead of `*` and vise versa.

Comment: Thank you @PeMa. I have clarified the statement.  I had neglected to mention the lazy turned greedy quantifiers.